# Точки над i

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли букву i заключать в кавычки? Некоторые источники утверждают, что не надо, но без кавычек как-то не смотрится. Так как же правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо кавычек.
Нет никаких причин. Скорее уж можно закавычить упоминаемые в тексте литеры И, О, А, С, К, У, Я когда они могут воспринияматься как местоимения, служебные слова (союзы, предлоги, частицы) или междоменития. I (десятеричное) ну никак нельзя спутать со словом современного языка (да и не только современного).

Ян, я не минчанин. )))

Answer (score 0):

Буква б — вторая буква русского алфавита.
Буква і — тоже буква русского алфавита.
Следует ставить точку над буквой і.
Расставьте все точки над і.

Comment: Интересно, что буква і заинтересовала исключительно минчан.:)

Comment: "Буква і -- тоже буква русского алфавита". Отвечу известным мемом: "Ты упоротый, что ли?"

Comment: Ответил бы и я, да воспитание не позволяет.
До революции была.

Comment: Раз сейчас у неё нет смысловой нагрузки, берется в кавычки.

Comment: То есть до революции не бралась, а сейчас берется??

Answer (score -1):

В художественной литературе, где я встречал такое выражение, везде "i" было заключено в кандалы кавычек.  Я тоже думаю, что без них фразеологизм выглядит немного кастрированным, так что стоит писать так: «Расставить все точки над "i"»
[Пруф, где "i" взята в кавычки.](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4_%C2%ABi%C2%BB)